# jquery autosuggest enterkey issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a field "**accountname**" that uses **Jquery autosuggest** in a textbox. Here as the user selects from the autosuggestion values and press **"Enter Key"** to fill with the selected value.
Currently i have mapped "Enter Key" to submit the form using **"Jquery hot keys"** plugin.

problem is, as soon as the user selects value from autosuggest, if he presses "Enter" to select. form is getting submitted. I dont want to submit the form, when the user presses enterkey in autosuggest dropdown. But should submit the form when the focus is on autosuggest field.

Which function needs to be overridden?

Here is my Snippet:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
         var availableTags = [
            // abbreviations                  
            {"label":"academy - acad","value":"acad"},{"label":"accident - acc","value":"acc"},{"label":"account - acct","value":"acct"}];

    function split( val ) {
        return val.split(/\s\s*/ );
    }

    function extractLast( term ) {
        return split( term ).pop();         
    }

    $("#accountName").bind( "keydown", function( event ) {
        if ( event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                $( this ).data( "autocomplete" ).menu.active ) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }

    }).autocomplete({
        minLength: 2,
        autoFocus: false,

        source: function( request, response ) {             
            // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
            response( $.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                    availableTags, extractLast( request.term ) ) );
        },
        focus: function() {             
            // prevent value inserted on focus
            return false;
            //return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {             
            var terms = split( this.value );
            // remove the current input
            terms.pop();
            // add the selected item
            terms.push( ui.item.value );
            // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
            terms.push( "" );
            this.value = terms.join(" ");

            // added to trim space
            $("#accountName").val($.trim($("#accountName").val()));

            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Please post a code sample which would be helpful.

Comment: Can you show your code? The select event should only populate the text field by default, so unless you've supplied your own select event, that's what it should be doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop the event propoagation on `select` event of `autocomplete`.

```
$( ".selector" ).autocomplete({
   select: function(event, ui) {  
       event.stopPropagation();
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The default behaviour of text input fields on **keypress** is to submit the form.

jQuery UI Autocomplete works by binding on the **keydown** event, and it checks whether ENTER is pressed while the menu's open and if so calls `event.preventDefault()` on **keypress** . Subsequent ENTERs don't `preventDefault` (unless the menu's open again).

So all of this works well naturally.

I can't say much more without seeing your code, but I'd say: let jQuery UI handle the ENTER key, and, if you need to, bind on `form.submit`.